# In-App purchases for users who already paid for the app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

My team and I developed a famous app (for WP7, also working on WP8). It has a lot of users who paid for the app. We now want to start using in-app purchases. My question is if users who initially paid for the app have to re-purchase the in-app purchases again? (-I don't hope so...)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Potentially useful but may not qualify as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641643/updating-a-previously-trialpaid-wp7-app-to-wp8-freein-app-purchases)

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you very much for your answer. To be honest, I really hope, that this is supported by the API somehow... Publishing a new app to the store (and updating everyone) is no possibility, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from the Microsoft Support. This was the answer:

> If you publish the app under the same product id, what you can do is use the store receipt to check the purchase date of the app and if your customer purchased it before a certain date, unlock all features. Otherwise, they must use the in-app purchase function to gain full access.
>
> Receipt documentation is below:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.getappreceiptasync.aspx
>
> One issue that you could run into, however, is WP7 apps do not support in-app purchases so this could present a problem if you wish to continue to support WP7 with the same product id.

Hope this help you too.

Comment: Doesn't help for Windows Phone, the `getAppReceiptAsync` is not yet implemented for WP8. When you use it it will throw an exception

Comment: So are there any working solutions for this scenario that you might have got?

Comment: What I did was to make the app free for WP7 (but limit some features for all who didn't purchase it before a given date) and provide the normal in-app purchase stuff for WP8. In the case of my app, there are only very few WP7 users left.

Comment: Well, Unfortunate! I took the Microsoft Developer Support from the Internal team itself, after a couple of days of research they said "it’s not something that has an easy solution at this time" - too bad Microsoft din't think of this scenario!

Comment: As @Shoaib pointed out this does not work for Windows Phone at all so this is not the answer.